# Showing that $M=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^4:x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=1,\ x_1x_2=x_3x_4\}$ is a 2-dimensional manifold and finding tangent planes

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I have solved the following problem and I would be grateful for any feedback on my solution, thanks.

> Let $M=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^4:x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=1,\ x_1x_2=x_3x_4\}$.
> (a) Show that $M$ is a smooth surface (2-dimensional manifold).
> (b) Find the tangent plane of $M$ at $\mathbf{a}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and at $\mathbf{a}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\-1/2\\-1/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}.$

What I have done:

a)
We consider $\mathbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^2,\ F\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3 \\ x_4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2-1\\ x_1x_2-x_3x_4\end{bmatrix}$.

$F$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function such that $M=F^{-1}(\{\mathbf{0}\})$ and $D\mathbf{F}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3 \\ x_4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2x_1 & 2x_2 & 2x_3 & 2x_4\\ x_2& x_1 & -x_4 & -x_3\end{bmatrix}.$

We want to show that rank$(D\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}))=2$ for $\mathbf{x}\in M.$

Now, either $x_1\neq 0$ or $x_1=0$.

If $\fbox{$x_1\neq 0$}$ we get $2x_1$ as the first pivot of our matrix and after a round of Gaussian elimination we are left with

$$\begin{bmatrix}2x_1 & 2x_2 & 2x_3 & 2x_4\\ 0 & \fbox{$x_1-\frac{x_2^2}{x_1}$} & -\frac{x_2x_3}{x_1}-x_4 & -\frac{x_2x_4}{x_1}-x_3\end{bmatrix}.$$

If $\fbox{$x_1\neq \pm x_2$}$ then our second would-be pivot, namely $x_1-\frac{x_2^2}{x_1}$ wouldn't be $0$ and we would have rank 2 as desired.

If instead $\fbox{$x_1=\pm x_2$}$ we would have:

for $\fbox{$x_1=x_2$}$
$$\begin{bmatrix}2x_2 & 2x_2 & 2x_3 & 2x_4\\ 0 & 0 & -x_3-x_4 & -x_3-x_4\end{bmatrix}.$$
To have rank $1$ it would then have to be $x_3=-x_4$ but in that case the second condition ($x_1x_2=x_3x_4$) tells us that we would have $x_2^2=-x_4^2$ which is impossible  (since $x_2^2>0$ and $x_4^2<0$). So, we have rank $2$ in this case;

for $\fbox{$x_1=-x_2$}$
$$\begin{bmatrix}-2x_2 & 2x_2 & 2x_3 & 2x_4\\ x_2 & -x_2 & -x_4 & -x_3\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}-2x_2 & 2x_2 & 2x_3 & 2x_4\\ 0 & 0 & x_3-x_4 & x_4-x_3\end{bmatrix}.$$
To have rank $1$ it would have to be $x_3=x_4$ but in that case the second condition ($x_1x_2=x_3x_4$) tells us that we would have $-x_2^2=x_4^2$ which is impossible  (since $-x_2^2<0$ and $x_4^2>0$). So, we have rank $2$ in this case.

So, if $x_1\neq 0$ we always have rank $2.$

Suppose now $\fbox{$x_1=0$}$:

if $\fbox{$x_2\neq 0$}$ we would have two pivots so rank $2$:
$$\begin{bmatrix} \fbox{$x_2$} & 0 & -x_4 & -x_3\\ 0 & \fbox{$2x_2$} & 2x_3 & 2x_4\end{bmatrix}$$

If $\fbox{$x_2=0$}$ we would also have (from the condition $x_1x_2=x_3x_4$) that either $x_3=0$ or $x_4=0$ (but not both, since that would violate the condition $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=1$) and in both cases we would also have two pivots and thus rank $2$:

$\fbox{$x_3=0$}$: $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & \fbox{$2x_4$}\\ 0 & 0 & \fbox{$-x_4$} & 0\end{bmatrix};$$

$\fbox{$x_4=0$}$: $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & \fbox{$2x_3$} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \fbox{$-x_3$}\end{bmatrix}.$$

So, we see that when $x_1=0$ we also always get rank $2$ so $D\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}),\ \mathbf{x}\in M$ always has rank 2 thus  $M=\mathbf{F}^{-1}(\{\mathbf{0}\})$ is a 2-dimensional manifold, as desired.

---

(b) The tangent plane of $M$  at $\mathbf{a}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is given by $D\mathbf{F}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1-1\\ x_2-0\\ x_3-0 \\ x_4-0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1-1\\ x_2\\ x_3 \\ x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2(x_1-1)\\x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}x_1=1\\x_2=0\end{cases}.$

The tangent plane of $M$  at $\mathbf{a}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\-1/2\\-1/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}$ is given by $D\mathbf{F}\begin{pmatrix}1/2\\-1/2\\-1/2\\-1/2\end{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1-1/2\\ x_2+1/2\\ x_3+1/2 \\ x_4-1/2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & -1 & 1\\ -1/2 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 1/2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1-1/2\\ x_2+1/2\\ x_3+1/2 \\ x_4-1/2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4-2\\x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4=2\\x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4=0\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}x_1-x_2=1\\ x_3-x_4=-1\end{cases}$

---

Note: I am aware that (the first part of) this same problem has been asked before but my approach is different from the answer given by a user to that question, and I would like to know/have feedback on what I have done.

Comment: For your first part, I didn't go through every algebraic detail because it's too tedious, but atleast you covered all the cases, and at one point even used the fact that we can't have $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=0$ since it would violate the condition $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=1$, so that's a good sign. So, I'd say your approach is fine, though it's very tedious. A much more efficient approach is to see that both rows are non-zero (otherwise they can't lie on the sphere) and are orthogonal (relative to the usual inner product on $\Bbb{R}^4$), so must be linearly independent, hence the matrix has rank 2.

Comment: @peek-a-boo very elegant method, thanks!

Comment: @peek-a-boo If you would write your comment as an answer, I would gladly accept it.